# How can I deduct Rental Real Estate Partnership loss?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, real-estate, rental-property, partnership

I am a limited partner in a Real Estate Partnership.  When I received my Tax Year 2022 form K-1 from the Partnership, it listed a loss in Box 2 - Rental Income or Loss.  Can I apply this loss to offset other parts of my income?  Which parts?   Thanks, Mark -- lapsed son of a CPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're in the US, given form K-1 for a partnership mentioned.

Generally up to [25K of rental losses can be deducted from other income](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p925#en_US_2022_publink1000104571), subject to MAGI limits.

As a limited partner in a RE partnership, your rental income/loss is passive activity, and may be subject to the passive activity loss limitations. Since we have no details about your tax situation, you'll need to check yourself if it applies to you. See [the IRS publication 925](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p925#en_US_2022_publink1000104571).